# acess ftp with wget through proxy

Tags: proxy, ftp, wget

i am currently stuck at a problem, that i think if i use a proxy, wget tries to connect to the server via http instead of ftp. Since i cannot post the full settings i will post an example of the behaviour I see:

Accessing the ftp server  without a proxy works using the command:

```
wget -r --user=username --password=mypassord ftp://ftp.myadress.com/
```

works as expected.

Accessing the ftp server with

```
wget -r --ftp-user=username --ftp-password=mypassord ftp://ftp.myadress.com/
```

works too.

Accessing the server with proxy and

```
wget -r --ftp-user=username --ftp-password=mypassord ftp://ftp.myadress.com/
```

leads to a

```
401 Unauthorized
```

error.

Using

```
wget -r --user=username --password=mypassord ftp://ftp.myadress.com/
```

leads to an index.html to be created. Unfortunately, the ftp server does not have any index.html files in the folders. Accessing a file with its full path through the proxy via

```
wget --user=username --password=mypassord ftp://ftp.myadress.com/test/test.txt
```

downloads the file as expected.

Accessing a different ftp server through the same proxy, which has an index.html in every folder with the command:

```
wget -r --user=username2 --password=mypassord2 ftp://ftp.myadress2.com/
```

works fine.

So how can i force wget to use the ftp protocol through the proxy?

Thanks in advance

Comment: update: it seems the proxy cannot convert the .listing it retrives from the ftp server into an index.html. Therefore, it creates an index.html, which only contrains the parent directory. I can reproduce this behaviour with curl, so i think it is a proxy problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put the proxy settings into a .wgetrc file instead?
It should contain something similar:

`use_proxy=yes
http_proxy=127.0.0.1:8080`

Comment: proxy is in the .wgetrc all the time i use it. As described i am sure the proxy itself is working, since i can download files if i specify the full path, or recrusive if the ftp server has the file listings in a index.html file.

Comment: And did you mention the FTP proxy as well in the .wgetrc file, like `ftp_proxy=127.0.0.1:8080` ?